# Directory.Build.targets for project files without targets in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

If my project file doesn't have any targets, and I have Directory.Build.targets file (with appropriate targets) in appropriate directory, Visual Studio cannot build project. Version of VS is 2019RC, but I don't think this is problem of particular version

Is that expected behavior, and why?

UPDATE - the full structure of the project. In general, this is modified project from "Data Connector Project" template of "Power Query SDK" - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dakahn.PowerQuerySDK

The project name is PQExtensionTest. It has typical folder structure - PQExtensionTest solution directory, inside PQExtensionTest.sln file and PQExtensionTest project directory with PQExtensionTest.mroj and Directory.build.targets files.

PQExtensionTest.sln file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28010.2046
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{4DF76451-A46A-4C0B-BE03-459FAAFA07E6}") = "PQExtensionTest", "PQExtensionTest\PQExtensionTest.mproj", "{6DEC2A2E-C380-4701-AA12-5052284223E4}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {6DEC2A2E-C380-4701-AA12-5052284223E4}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {6DEC2A2E-C380-4701-AA12-5052284223E4}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {6DEC2A2E-C380-4701-AA12-5052284223E4}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {6DEC2A2E-C380-4701-AA12-5052284223E4}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {50EB6857-946A-4D05-B65C-B99E4D39BEDD}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

PQExtensionTest.mroj file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{6dec2a2e-c380-4701-aa12-5052284223e4}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="PQExtensionTest.pq">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Content Include="PQExtensionTest.query.pq">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Directory.Build.targets file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildExtension" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{a9cd1ca9-92e5-493d-8065-377910605c30}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyRootNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>False</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <AllowNativeQuery>False</AllowNativeQuery>
    <AsAction>False</AsAction>
    <FastCombine>False</FastCombine>
    <ClearLog>False</ClearLog>
    <ShowEngineTraces>False</ShowEngineTraces>
    <ShowUserTraces>False</ShowUserTraces>
    <LegacyRedirects>False</LegacyRedirects>
    <SuppressRowErrors>False</SuppressRowErrors>
    <SuppressCellErrors>False</SuppressCellErrors>
    <MaxRows>1000</MaxRows>
    <ExtensionProject>Yes</ExtensionProject>
    <Name>PQExtensionTest</Name>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <!--Should be true, fix this when the debugger is implemented -->
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="BuildExtension" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputDirectory ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <OutputFile ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
      <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Globalization" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO.Compression " />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[    
    using(FileStream fileStream = File.Create(OutputFile))
    using(ZipArchive archiveOut = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
    {
        foreach(string fullPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(InputDirectory))
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);

            archiveOut.CreateEntryFromFile(fullPath, filename, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }
    }
]]></Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
  <Target Name="BuildExtension" DependsOnTargets="ExtensionClean">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PQFiles Include="@(Compile)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.pq'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <NonPQFiles Include="@(Compile)" Condition="'%(Extension)' != '.pq'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(NonPQFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(PQFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PQFiles->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName).m')" />
    <BuildExtension InputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" OutputFile="$(OutputPath)\$(ProjectName).mez" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ExtensionClean">
    <!-- Remove obj folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <!-- Remove bin folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
<Message Text="MyM: $(aProperty)" />
   </Target>
```

Comment: If possible, could you please share a simple sample of your project file and Directory.Build.targets file. The result of the build can be affected by many factors during this process. So it's hard to say if it's an expected behavior without your these two files.

Comment: Hi, I've checked your update and I'm afraid this project type seems not support your situation. This project type is an extension from third-party not from VS developer team.And after I test, this extension has special check process which differs a lot from VS projects.(C# C++...) For eg: Create a new project, delete the two targets in its proj file. Reload and you will find the build option disappears!!!

Comment: And for the error:E_INVALIDARG. Add PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <!--Should be true, fix this when the debugger is implemented -->
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup> to the proj file can help load. Not sure why, the check process  is quite strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that expected behavior, and why?

**It depends.**

**1**. First, according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets),the `Directory.Build.targets` only works after the `Microsoft.Common.props` calls it.

So if you haven't imported the `Microsoft.Common.props` (or `.targets`) in a project file, the build will fail.

In this situation,it's a expected behavior that we can't build project with no targets in project file.

**2**. As you mentioned *"I have Directory.Build.targets file (with appropriate targets)"*, please make sure you have `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` in your project file. Without it, the build can't work for your situation (with no custom targets in project file).

Make sure you've imported `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` in project file. And for your targets in `Directory.Build.targets`, add an attribute `<Target BeforeTargets="...">` or `<Target AfterTargets="...">` to make it work.

Example for my `Directory.Build.targets`:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="build">
    <Message Text="..."/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Only when you've met these points can you build successfully in your situation.So please check it.

**Update:**

For a custom `.proj` file. We must have a target defined directly in `.proj` file or have a target imported with other targets files.

Since there is no targets in your proj file, and no targets in your Imported targets will be run, MSBuild will throw the error `MSB4040` (There is no target in Project). Because if no target runs, then it doesn't make sense for the MSBuild process. This is the feature by design.

**Update2**

In a `test.sln`, I have a `Directory.build.props` in the solution directory:

```
<Project  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Today">
    <Message Text="JustForTest"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And a quite simple .csproj file in project dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
</Project>
```

If I build the `test.csproj`, the build can succeed and run the Today Target to output "JustForTest". And if I comment out the Import `Microsoft.Common.Props`, the build will fail with `MSB4040`. Cause in .NET, the `Directory.build.props` **can not be imported implicitly** without the `Microsoft.Common.Props`.

**Update3**

I've checked the content of `microsoft.common.props` and `microsoft.Csharp.targets`.
In M.C.P file, there has definition and calls about Directory.build.props. While in M.C.T file, it defines the standard build process of C#. So I agree that there must be something in your project file which calls Directory.build.props, but that can't be microsoft.Csharp.targets or microsoft.VB.targets.
[image]

Comment: 1. I have targets in Directory.Build.targets. But only in that file. So it is unhallowed? 

2. "the Directory.Build.targets only works after the Microsoft.Common.props call it" - you mean Directory.Build.targets will be imported **after** Microsoft.Common.props imported, or **if** Microsoft.Common.props imported, or something else?

Comment: For1, as I mentioned above, in a situation where we only have targets in Directory.Build.targets, and only in that file, if we can build the project or not depends on whether we have a "Microsoft.Common.props" to call it, or something have the similar function like "Microsoft.Common.props".

Comment: For2, yes, I have just checked it again. In a C# project, it uses Microsoft.Common.props to implicitly import the Directory.Build.targets, if I comment that import Microsoft.Common.props, then the build will fall for no targets is imported into proj file. i will add some details to my update soon, you can check it.

Comment: In addition: If the Directory.build.props can't be implicitly imported into your project file where has no targets, you can't build the project unless explicitly import it by <Import Project="..\Directory.Build.props" />

Comment: "i will add some details to my update soon, you can check it" - please could you say where can I check the update? Thanks.

Regarding the error - I even cannot "load" the project, when I open such a project (a project without any target but in Directory.Build.targets), I see the poject in "unload" state, and if I try to load it, I get an error. So I cannot see which Microsoft.Common* files are used for build for such a project.

Comment: Hi what project type in visual studio? Maybe I can create a project type as what you use, and then I can research the structure of it. Also, even we have no targets in project file and both Directory.Build.targets file, the build will fail while the reload can succeed. So could you please share the error message when you try to load, I assume there maybe some Syntax errors. (And see update2, I try to describe what I mean the Directory.build.targets is called by another import project)

Comment: The error is E_INVALIDARG.

BTWN - I looked through my mporj file, and realized that there is import of Microsoft.CSharp.targets for inline task there. And I suspect, that all Directory.Build* stuff works for me just because there is that import. Is that correct? So without import of Microsoft.CSharp.targets or Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets all that Directory.Build.* magic disappears.

Comment: Ok, I'll place the whole project structure in update for my post. Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it after your update. Any question please feel free to contact me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190349/discussion-between-andrey-minakov-and-lance-li-msft).